# How to fit a line between areas of high density? (find valley between hills in 3D)

Tags: density-estimation, image-segmentation

My data are a number of points in 2 dimensions. There are areas that are more dense. I run a kernel density estimation with a Gaussian filter that gives me a result similar to the picture (of course, way more noisy than this example..). The red areas would be areas of high density. There is a gap in between, like a valley between two hills. I am looking for a line that separates these hills: The green line in the image.

[image: looking for the green line]

It doesn't have to be a perfect fit. I therefore went for sampling the area at different x-values and used peak detection to find the local minima of the line over y. Unfortunately, in the noisy data this approach is too unstable, so it would be good to find a way to find the optimal line directly in the 2D image

I also tried a watershed approach, but the threshold and distance measurements aren't straight forward, since usually one of the two areas is way smaller than the other. I managed to separate the areas sometimes, but that still didn't give me the line I am looking for.

I'm working in python. So, if you can point me to any library, that would be greatly appreciated. But also knowing the name of an algorithm would help, because I don't know what to google for.. Thanks!

**Edit for more info on the data:**

Here is an example data set. You may realize that you cannot really see a distinctive separation between different areas, but you might appreciate that some areas are more dense than others.

[image: points]

Using the standard Gaussian KDE from [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) I obtain a density distribution heatmap that does show what I am looking for (in some cases it's way more clear, in others even less. I chose a medium clear example here).

[image: density]

In a 3D view this looks like a hill with a valley between two peaks.

[image: hill]

This hill can look different every time with some smaller valleys and more than 2 peaks. But usually there is one major valley, which is what I am looking for. The "height" of hill and valley is different every time.

In the end I want to sort the points in the first image whether they belong to the upper or the lower hill. Therefore I need this valley as the border between them.

Comment: There are a great many solutions possible. As an example, if you negate all values you can interpret your problem as one of drawing a "ridgeline" across a mountain range--and this is something a good GIS can do. (Google "topographic feature extraction".)  Whether that would be a good solution is difficult to determine, because you haven't supplied several essential pieces of information.  First, what is this line intended to represent; and second, what is your probability model for the data?

Comment: Thanks @whuber I will look into it. I also provided more details in the question.